# How to match password in php when storing only password in database?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I am storing only password hash in database no email or username for privacy reasons. Currently I am using following code to insert hashed password in database for registration. 20 character unique Password is created by code user cannot create his own password

```
$pass='1234567';
$storethispasshash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
```

To match the stored password on login page I am using

```
$db->where ('password', $_POST['pass']);
$results = $db->getOne ('register');
$pass = password_hash( $_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
password_verify($pass,$results['password'])
```

but password_verify is returning false. What can I do in this case?
Thanks

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php you dont hash the password parameter. https://3v4l.org/ZDI7p

Comment: .... You can't do that. When you store a password correctly hashed+salted you can't* find it in the database with the clear text password. (*you would need to hash your input with every salt in the db).... what if 2 users have the same password "1234567"?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am storing hashed password in first and then I want to retrieve the password from database. For that don't I need to hash the password entered on login page to match with database password as user will not enter hashed password? I don't have email or username to match the record in database. I have only password.

Comment: @RolandStarke Ok so I will need to generate hash for each password and store it in a column and then match it on login page.

Comment: @RolandStarke Is right as its random salted each call to password_hash will produce a different hash, if your going to do this, your need to store an additional hash to match which is fixed salted and does not change, but that defeats the purpose.. Also how would you differentiate users with the same password? If you prevent the same password, then your disclosing someone's password. lol bad design imo, just use a standard username/password.. my2cent

Comment: @LawrenceCherone random 20 character passwords are being generated by code. User cannot create his own password. So there is no chance of same password.

Comment: @deepsingh If you want to go this route and have a password only login then I can simply try any 20 char passwords and sooner or later I will be logged into some account. If you have to keep the "no username, no email" policy then simply have the user log in with their id + password, preferably an uuid like `f043570e-5f91-4f98-a9c3-2ca76a8bcb53`. I'd also recommend just letting the users choose their own password. Any limit you set on passwords actually reduce the entropy of the passwords in your app.